# Map one keypress to another in PyQT Table

Tags: python, vim, pyqt, qubes-os

I'd like to add the Vim `j` and `k` keybinds to a PyQT application. The application is the Qubes OS [Qube Manager](https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-manager) and it consists mostly of a table. I'd like the Vim `j` and `k` keybinds to move the selected table row "down" and "up", respectively.

On what layer should I implement this? Can I map `j` and `k` in the application itself? Would I have to add something to the table and related classes?

Can I do this while only understanding the basics of PyQT?

Comment: `j` and `k` don't do anything even remotely like that in Vim so why bother?

Comment: Use [QShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html).